# ::before not affected my width and height

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I am currently making a Pricing Template for a client and it involves using check boxes, but I hate the look of the default ones, so I am styling them myself. I have never styled check boxes before but this is how I am attempting to. The codepen is [here.](http://codepen.io/TheAndersMan/pen/QEygpG?editors=0100) My what isn't working starts on line 101 in the HTML and 129 of the CSS. Also I am using SCSS.

I am using ::before to style them and I set the check boxes to have a max-height of 0. The problem is that when I set a width and height for it, it doesn't affect it at all.

Here is the basic HTML:

```
  <div class="cellBottom cell alaCart">
    <section>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
    </section>
  </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
    section p input[type="checkbox"] {
      max-height: 0px;
    }
    section p input[type="checkbox"]::before {
      content: "ahhhh";
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      background: #555;
    }
```

So is there something I'm missing? I am fairly new to ::before and ::after, but I think I understand the basics.

Can someone help?

Comment: Inputs are void elements. You can't insert content inside them (at all or in a reliable way, depending on the browser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to set `width` or `height`, you need to set your `display` type to a `block`, `inline-block` or any display type that "creates layout".

```css
section p input[type="checkbox"] {
    max-height: 0px;
}

section p input[type="checkbox"]::before {
    content: "ahhhh";
    display: inline-block;
    background: #555;
}
```

```html
  <div class="cellBottom cell alaCart">
    <section>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" />Lorem ipsum</p>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @TheAndersMan great! Please upvote and mark the question correct if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`max-height` is absolute. If the `height` goes over `max-height`, the `max-height` takes priority.

As per the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height):

> The `max-height` property is used to set the maximum height of an element. It prevents the used value of the height property from becoming larger than the value specified for `max-height`.

Therefore, by specifying `max-height` to 0px, the height *cannot ever* go over 0px, even if explicitly set to something larger.